# which library should I use for big data project

Tags: java, python, bigdata

The project aims to analyzing the patients’ illness cells using Big Data technology to indicate which treatments could have the best outcomes and fewest side effects.

But I think using python or java library. I can't decide which language's library is more useful for my project. if you have any experience , could you help me. I do not know about anything about big data.

Comment: What are "the patients’ illness cells", and what does "Big Data technology" mean to you?

Comment: illness is general term of the project detail. Big data technology mean huge data. I research for the most effective method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/).  It's got just about every library you'll need for big data analysis bundled into one installer.

The Anaconda distro also includes [Disco MapReduce](http://discoproject.org/), so you have all the tools you need to set up a distributed file system MapReduce farm for really large analysis jobs.

Comment: thanks so much. So you said is python more useful ?

Comment: You can use python or java.  If you go with java, you'll want to do deep dive into Hadoop.  Java/Hadoop solutions have a lot more main-stream usage than Disco/python, but the learning curve is also a little steeper.